# How to check the jdk build version and vendor used to compile a .class file?

Tags: java

Linux Mint 20.2

To check the jdk version used to compile a .class file I used this:

```
javap -verbose MyClass | grep "major"
```

Result:

```
52
```

Nice. But it not enough.

I can compile java file by **jdk1.8.0_202_Oracle** or by **openjdk-8u322-b06**.

So is it possible to see the vendor name and the build version used to compile a .class file?

Comment: I don't think class file will have build version of the JDK used for compiling since it's not necessary.

Comment: It's more complex than that. You can have 1.8 as target, but compiling with later versions of the JDK. The best place is probably the jar's manifest file, but you can't count on that, unless you built it yourself.